# Show css to super admin only

Tags: php, css, wordpress

My goal is to hide specific tables with CSS on WordPress dashboard, from all users except super admin.

```
<?php is_super_admin( $user_id ); ?>

add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_custom_function' );
function my_custom_function() {
 if ( ! current_user_can( 'update_core' ) ) {
   echo '<style>p.smush-status {
   display: none;
   }
   button.button.wp-smush-send  {
   display: none;
   }
   #smushit {
   display:none;
   }</style>';
 }
});
```

But, when I'm adding this code to mu-plugins, I got the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in
>   /home/.../public_html/domain.com/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line
>   1614

capabilities.php it's WordPress core file.

Would you please have a look and tell me how can I improve this code?

Thank you

Comment: Did you read this? *For wordpress versions < 3.4: use the init or any subsequent action to call this function. Calling it outside of an action can lead to troubles. See [#14024](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/14024) for details.*

Comment: I'm not into Wordpress but simply hiding critical things using CSS for non-admins seems to not be the right way. The client can change all CSS anyways. If you're certain you want this, how about adding a class ("admin") to an element up in the hierarchy and referencing all other elements as descendant elements in CSS selectors (e.g. ".admin #smushit")?

Answer (score 0):

Do not use css to hide part of the admin dashboard, this is a security breach.
You must to unset it using  a function added in your theme functions.php:

```
// Create the function to use in the action hook

function remove_dashboard_widgets() {


    global $wp_meta_boxes;

    // Remove the quickpress widget

    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['side']['core']['dashboard_quick_press']);

    // Remove the incomming links widget

    unset($wp_meta_boxes['dashboard']['normal']['core']['dashboard_incoming_links']);
} 

// Hoook into the 'wp_dashboard_setup' action to register our function
if(!is_admin()){
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'remove_dashboard_widgets' );
}
```

Edit: and dont edit wordpress core files aswell, you will lost everything because of update.

Comment: Thank you Bipbip, I did not know that using css to hide part of admin dashboard it is a security breach. I wont use this then. Then Can I wrap(?) a code from a plugin, that calling to show some statistic in dashboard, to be only viewed to a super admin?

Comment: Check the function, it is only call if user is not an admin, you can paste it in your fonctions.php in your theme and should work if you replace the arguments by the ones of the plugin.